# For each group, how can I replace values for previous years if a recent year has a certain value?

Tags: python, pandas, replace, pandas-groupby

I have the dataframe `df` below. Each person has actual quantities listed for one or more years.

**For each person**, starting with the most recent year, when a value of `0` is present, I want to replace the values in prior years with `0` as shown in the `desired quantity` column.

How can I accomplish this?

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'person': ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'e'],
     'year': [2000, 2000, 2001, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2003],
     'actual quantity': [2, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 4, 3, 0, 1, 1],
     'desired quantity': [2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

```
+--------+------+-----------------+------------------+
| person | year | actual quantity | desired quantity |
+--------+------+-----------------+------------------+
| a      | 2000 |               2 |                2 |
| b      | 2000 |               0 |                0 |
| b      | 2001 |               1 |                1 |
| c      | 2000 |               3 |                0 |
| c      | 2001 |               0 |                0 |
| c      | 2002 |               1 |                1 |
| d      | 2000 |               4 |                0 |
| d      | 2001 |               3 |                0 |
| d      | 2002 |               0 |                0 |
| d      | 2003 |               1 |                1 |
| e      | 2003 |               1 |                1 |
+--------+------+-----------------+------------------+
```

Comment: would [where method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) do for you?

Comment: If it can produce the desired result, sure. I’m familiar with `np.where` which from the docs seems similar. I’m still not sure how to apply it in this case, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need first [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) each column differently, then use [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) with custom mask - compare values by `0`, convert to integers by [`Series.view`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html), create sumulative sum per groups by [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html) and last compare for not equal `0`:

```
df = df.sort_values(['person','year'], ascending=[True, False])
m = (df['actual quantity'].eq(0)
                          .view('i1')
                          .groupby(df['person'])
                          .cumsum()
                          .ne(0))

df['desired quantity1'] = df['actual quantity'].mask(m, 0)
df = df.sort_index()
print (df)
   person  year  actual quantity  desired quantity  desired quantity1
0       a  2000                2                 2                  2
1       b  2000                0                 0                  0
2       b  2001                1                 1                  1
3       c  2000                3                 0                  0
4       c  2001                0                 0                  0
5       c  2002                1                 1                  1
6       d  2000                4                 0                  0
7       d  2001                3                 0                  0
8       d  2002                0                 0                  0
9       d  2003                1                 1                  1
10      e  2003                1                 1                  1
```

Comment: It does produce the desired result, but this might be by coincidence due to the way I structured my example. I’ll test it on a larger dataset, but I have a feeling a reliable solution should incorporate a groupby `person` to make sure the replacement happens for each person.

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. See updated sample. The last row should be a `1` but your code outputs `0`.

Comment: @InsuQ - I try to understand `For each person, starting with the most recent year, when a value of 0 is present, I want to replace the values in prior years with 0 as shown in the desired quantity column.` but expected output is different. It seems persoms `a,b,c,d` are not important from expected output, only frst row of each unique year. person `e` it is different. Can you explain more `For each person, starting with the most recent year, when a value of 0 is present, I want to replace the values in prior years with 0 as shown in the desired quantity column.` ?

Comment: Hi @jezrael, when a person has a quantity of 0, I want to keep that value as 0 and then replace all values in each of the previous years for that person to 0. Person `e` doesn’t have any values that are 0 so the output remains the same (in this case 1), as expected. Does that make sense? I *think* sorting by year ascending is needed to not “forward fill” the values when a 0 is encountered (this is already done in the sample), and then a groupby person is needed to constrain the replacement for each person. I’m just not sure how to implement it.

Comment: for person `c` year 2001 is the last time he has a `0`, so we replace the values in all prior years for that person to `0` (for person `c` replace the `3` in year 2000 with `0`. For person `d` the last time there’s `0` is 2002, so replace values in all prior years for that person to `0`. It’s important to do by person and to look at the last (or “most recent”) since someone can have `0` in year 2003, a non-0 in 2002, a `0` in 2001, and a non-0 in 2000. In this case, we look at the `0` in the max year 2003 and replace the values in 2000-2002 with `0` (that person would have all zeroes)

Comment: I also tried to groupby person and shift actual quantity back by 1 step to see if there’s a zero in the next step then replace the value with zero, but this only works for one step. For person d, this would help me replace the 3 in 2001 because the shifted value is 0 but not the 4 in 2001 because the shifted value would be 3.

Comment: this is very clever. your solution worked perfectly, thanks!